# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined TypeError

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, promise

I am working on an Ionic app and I have following method which calls an observable :

```
  getCountryById(id: number): Promise<Country> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.getCountries().subscribe(countries => {
        for (let country of countries) {
          if (country.Id == id) {
            resolve(country);
          }
        }
        resolve(undefined);
      }, err => reject(err));
    })
  }
```

The other method:

```
  getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
    if (this.countries) {
      return Observable.of(this.countries);
    } else if (this.countriesObservable) {
      return this.countriesObservable;
    } else {

      this.storage.get(AppSettings.STORAGE_KEYS.LANGUAGE_APP).then(
        language=>{
          this.countriesObservable = this.http.get(AppSettings.API_URL + 'api/Countries?locale=' + language).map(json => {
            delete this.countriesObservable; // when the cached countries is available we don't need the `countriesObservable` reference anymore
            this.countries = json as Country[];
            this.countries = this.countries.sort(function (a, b) { return (a.Name > b.Name) ? 1 : ((b.Name > a.Name) ? -1 : 0); });
            return this.countries;
          }).share();
        }
      ).catch(err=>{
      });

      return this.countriesObservable;

    }

  }
```

I am pretty sure I am returning wrong data. How should I refactor the second method to return valid Observable so that first method can work on this.I am still trying to wrap my head around Promise and Observable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, when `this.countriesObservable` is `undefined`, you are calling `this.storage.get(...).then(...)`. Inside the callback to tha promise you are setting `this.countriesObservable`.

The problem is that, when you reach the `return this.countriesObservable`, the callback to `then` has not been executed, and so you're still returning `undefined`.

You must assign `this.countriesObservable` to a new `Observable` before calling `this.storage.get` (maybe a `Subject`), then, inside the `then`, you just listen to the Observable you were going to return, and inside its call to `subscribe`, feed `this.countriesObservable` witht the data you want:

```
const _subject = new Subject<Country[]>();
this.countriesObservable = _subject;
this.storage.get(AppSettings.STORAGE_KEYS.LANGUAGE_APP).then(
    language=>{
        this.http.get(AppSettings.API_URL + 'api/Countries?locale=' + language).map(json => {
            delete this.countriesObservable; // when the cached countries is available we don't need the `countriesObservable` reference anymore
            this.countries = json as Country[];
            this.countries = this.countries.sort(function (a, b) { return (a.Name > b.Name) ? 1 : ((b.Name > a.Name) ? -1 : 0); });
            return this.countries;
          }).subscribe(countries => _subject.next(countries));
        }
    ).catch(err=>{});

return this.countriesObservable;
```

You might have to make a few adjustments, but this is the idea. Hope it serves you.